# Is it necessary to load dynamic images in the background anymore?

Tags: javascript, html

Say I have some HTML markup, an image with a placeholder:

```html
<img class="lazy-load"
  src="http://via.placeholder.com/150/?text=placeholder"
  data-src="http://via.placeholder.com/150/?text=real%20image"/>
```

And at some point, I want to load the real image through some lazy loading strategy.

What I'm used to is loading the real image in the background before displaying it, like this:

```js
// Load real image in background to prevent FOUC
const img = document.querySelector(".lazy-load");
const realSrc = img.dataset.src;
const bgImg = new Image();
bgImg.src = realSrc;
bgImg.onload = () => { img.src = realSrc; }
```

I was under the impression that waiting for the browser to load the content in the background and then displaying it, I would prevent FOUC. But it looks like without waiting for the onload there is no FOUC:

```js
// Not worrying about loading image in the background as there is no FOUC
const img = document.querySelector(".lazy-load");
img.src = img.dataset.src;
```

Is it still necessary to load images in the background before adding them to the document, or are browsers smart enough to wait for the new image to load before replacing the old one?

Comment: I can't test it right now. But did you ensure that you have disabled browser caching, and enabled throttling of the connection to test if FOUC would occur without preloading?

Comment: That's a good question. I made a quick POC with a Node server that I think solves this.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to draft up this client and server example. Refer to the following snippets:

```js
// slow-server.js
// for any request, wait a few seconds, then serve an image.
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const app = express();
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    const file = path.join(__dirname, "real.png");
    const stream = fs.createReadStream(file);

    stream.on("open", () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            res.set("Content-Type", "image/png");
            stream.pipe(res);
        }, 6000);
    })
});
app.listen(3001, () => console.log("listening on 3001"));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title>Dynamic Load</title>
    <style>
        img {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="placeholder.png" data-src="http://localhost:3001/real.png" />
    <button class="replace">Lazy load</button>
    <button class="add">Add new</button>
    <script>
        const replaceButton = document.querySelector("button.replace");
        replaceButton.addEventListener("click", e => {
            replaceButton.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
            replaceButton.innerText = 'loading...';
            const img = document.querySelector("img");
            img.src = img.dataset.src;
        });

        const addButton = document.querySelector("button.add");
        addButton.addEventListener("click", e => {
            addButton.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
            addButton.innerText = 'loading...';
            const img = new Image();
            img.src = "http://localhost:3001/real.png";
            document.body.appendChild(img);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When the Replace button is clicked, the browser loads the new src in the background and then replaces the old one once it receives the image from the server.

When the Add button is clicked, we can see that a 0 width/0 height image tag has been added to the page, and when the image is received, the image shows on the screen.

So in the `Replace` scenario, it seems like the `img.onload` trick is unnecessary.

In the `Add` scenario, we should wait for the image to be loaded before adding it to the document.